# 'TypeError' or 'expected numeric' error in ruby code while drawing Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm Using **Highcharts** to display **Embedded Real Data** from database. The code for my data is given below.

```
............
............
 series: [{
      pointInterval: <%= 3.day * 1000 %>,
      pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
      data: <%= (3.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Linkclick.total_clicks(@link,date)}.inspect %>
    }]
.............
...........
```

The problem is that it's giving me an error on the line

```
  data: <%= (3.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Linkclick.total_clicks(@link,date)}.inspect %>
```

saying...

```
expected numeric

Extracted source (around line #110):

107:     series: [{
108:       pointInterval: <%= 3.day * 1000 %>,
109:       pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
110:       data: <%= (3.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Linkclick.total_clicks(@link,date)}.inspect %>
111:     }]
112:   });
113:     });
```

The model method that is being called is given below:-

```
def self.total_clicks(link,date)
    linkclick=Linkclick.where("link=? AND created_at LIKE ?", link, date + "%")
    logger.info "===ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss=================#{linkclick.inspect}"
    logger.info "===sssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=================#{linkclick.class}"
    logger.info "===sssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb=================#{linkclick.count.inspect}" 
    return linkclick.count
  end
```

The logger.info in the model showing exactly How the data should flow. But Due to the problem graph is not being displayed. 
So, what's the issue with my code...
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to update your `self.total_clicks(link, date)` method with this change:

```
linkclick = Linkclick.where('link = ? AND DATE(created_at) = ?', link, date)
```

Comment: Cool, It working now...As I'm new to rails I would just like to ask you what was wrong with whatever I was doing..Just a little explanation would be great... Thanks...

Comment: There was two bad things: ruby related, and SQL related.

**Ruby:** You've tried to add string ('%') to Date object, that's not good if you do not .to_s your date (you can add to Date object integer for examples without any warnings - so you get increased date)

**SQL:** created_at have a DATETIME SQL type (in MySQL/Postgresql), and for example, Postgres do not run `created_at LIKE 'string%'` queries at all. Much better if you get the date part from created_at field by DB inner function and make a straight checking, as I show in the answer.